# Number of solution of the equation $\cot^{-1}{\sqrt{4-x^2}+ \cos^{-1}{(x^2-5)}}=3π/2$

Tags: inverse, inverse-function

> Number of solution of the equation $ \cot^{-1}{\sqrt{4-x^2} + \cos^{-1}{(x^2-5)}}=3\pi/2$

$$ \cot^{-1}{\sqrt{4-x^2}+ \cos^{-1}{(x^2-5)}}={3π/2}$$
Taking sine both side and solving this is I get
$$1 +\sqrt{5-x^2}x^2-4 \sqrt{5-x^2}+\sqrt{4-x^2}+\sqrt{x^6-15x^4+74x^2-120}=0$$
After this, I can't solve it and my approach is time taking also, so plz suggest me a simple approach and less time taking.

Comment: is it $\cos^{-1} x^2$ or $\cos^{-1} (x^2-5)$  ?

Comment: Yes..  you r correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression requires
$$
\begin{cases}
x^2\le 4 \\[4px]
|x^2-5|\le 1
\end{cases}
$$
In particular, $x^2-5\ge-1$, that is, $x^2\ge 4$.

Comment: That's a brilliant answer. Thanks

Comment: @egreg For the sake of completeness, would you consider adding the actual conclusion? That the expression is defined for only two values of $x$ and that they do verify the equation.

Answer (score 2):

Using principal values of inverse trigonometric functions,

As $a=\sqrt{4-x^2}$ is defined and $\ge0$ for $4-x^2\ge0$

$\cot^{-1}a\le\dfrac\pi2$

and $\cos^{-1}(x^2-5)$ is defined and $\le\pi$ if $-\le x^2-5\le1$

So, the required equality will occur if $x^2-4=0$ and $x^2-5=-1$